# Xamarin.Forms TapRecognizer on android cancels ItemTapped Event

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a custom control on Xamarin Forms that contains a gesture recognizer.

ImageLabelControl.xaml

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="Container"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="Recognizer" Tapped="Recognizer_OnTapped" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <Image x:Name="ImageCell" />
        <Label x:Name="LabelCell" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

ImageLabelControl.xaml.cs

```
 ...

 private void Recognizer_OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       //ExecuteIfPossible just checks if the CanExecute of the ICommand returns true
       Command?.ExecuteIfPossible(CommandParameter);
 }

 ...
```

when i use the above control on a ListView the `ItemTapped` Event when running on *Android* never gets fired. On *UWP* the event gets fired as expected.

ListView Test Case:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DropdownOptionsCommands}">
            <ListView.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
                    EventName="ItemTapped"
                    Command="{Binding ExecuteDropdownCommand}" />
            </ListView.Behaviors>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <controls:ImageLabelControl WidthRequest="200"
                                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                    ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl,Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"
                                                    ImageHeightRequest="30"
                                                    ImageMargin="20,5,20,5"
                                                    ImageVerticalOptions="Center"
                                                    Text="{Binding Text}"
                                                    LabelMargin="20,5,20,5"
                                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                    LabelVerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Implementation of EventToCommandBehavior on [github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior/EventToCommandBehavior/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior.cs)

`ExecuteDropdownCommand`

```
if (!(e is ItemTappedEventArgs ev)) return;

if (!(ev.Item is OptionCommands comm)) return;

if (comm.Command == null) return;

comm.Command.ExecuteIfPossible(comm.CommandParameter);
```

`DropdownOptionsCommands` is an `ObservableCollection` of `OptionCommands`

```
 public class OptionCommands
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public ICommand Command { get; set; }

    public object CommandParameter { get; set; }

    public OptionCommands()
    { }

    public OptionCommands(string text, ICommand command, object parameter = null)
    {
        Text = text;
        Command = command;
        CommandParameter = parameter;
    }

    public OptionCommands(string imageUrl, string text, 
    ICommand command, object parameter = null) : this(text, command, parameter)
    {
        ImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
```

If you need more info please leave a comment.

Thank you.

Comment: I would try to put a background colour to the ListView! Sounds like a similar problem: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99978/different-tap-handling-in-android-and-uwp

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer I will try it!

Answer (score 2):

I would try to put a background colour to the ListView! 
Sounds like a similar problem: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99978/different-tap-handling-in-android-and-uwp 
*Just posted it as an answer, it could help someone someday.*